# How to remove sequence line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

**I have this line**

```
Apple   
Monkey
Orange
Lion
fruit
animal
Fish
Tiger
Rose
but 
in 
that 
case 
it 
will 
first 
delete 
the
instead 
of 
really 
looking 
for 
an 
odd 
line.
line 
your 
cursor 
is 
in, 
You 
could 
also 
check 
"wrap 
around",  
ons 
about 
computer 
software 
or 
computer
about
he
the
de 
details 
and 
share
```

**I want to delete line number** : 1,8,15,22,29,36,43,50

The final result like this

```
Monkey
Orange
Lion
fruit
animal
Fish
Rose
but 
in 
that 
case 
it 
first 
delete 
the
instead 
of 
really 
for 
an 
odd 
line.
line 
your 
is 
in
You 
could 
also 
check 
around"
ons 
about 
computer 
software 
or 
about
he
the
de 
details 
and 
share
```

**How I can do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Important: position the cursor at the very begining of the file.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\R((?:.+\R){6})`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(           # group 1
    (?:         # non capture group
        .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
        \R          # any kind of linebreak
    ){6}        # end group, must appear 6 times
)           # end group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Its works fine, thanks for your answer

Comment: @jamj: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: accepted, love to see your response, wish you all the best